# Salesforce Single Logout (SLO) configuration with multiple relying party

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, open-id-connect, logout

In one of the Salesforce implementation I am working on, a single Connected App is being used for Single-Sign-On (Community users) for multiple relying parties (using OpenId protocol). SSO is working fine. Also if users log out from a relying party, they are also logs out from Salesforce. However when they log out from the Salesforce Community, they are not being log out from other relying parties.

In the Salesforce Connected App we have one configuration called 'Single Logout URL' however here we can configure logout URL for only one relying party. Is there any way I can provide multiple Single Logout URL for all relying parties? Or this current setup is not correct and we should create separate connected app, one for each relying party?

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody responded yet therefore answering my own question for other's benefit. Based on my analysis what I learnt is that just by selecting 'openid' scope in the OAuth based Connected App doesn't make it IdP or Authentication Provider (It's Salesforce Org which represent IdP). Connected Apps always represent your Service Providers (SPs). Hence I came to a conclusion that current design is incorrect and individual Connected Apps should be defined for each Service Provider. In that way IdP knows the Single Logout URL for all SPs registered with IdP/OpenID Connect.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble with Single Logout in our Salesforce integration. When Salesforce redirects to our SLO url, I'm unable to identify the user to trigger logout on our end because the session log in already end. Have you faced a similar issue? Any suggestions? Thanks